# Xamarin Forms Shell - Burger Menu with Pages with complex constructors

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create Page with burger menu using Xamarin.Forms Shell. The menu would contains Pages: HomePage (with compex constructor) and AboutPage (with default constructor). There is no problem with AboutPage, because it can be created easly in xaml, but i have no idea how to add new ShellItem with HomePage

I have tried to create this menu item from xaml.cs, but the doesn't render.

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
 public AppShell(IDataProvider dataProvider)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Items.Add(new ShellItem()
            {
                Title = "Home", Items = { new ShellSection()
                {
                    CurrentItem = new ShellContent()
                    {
                        Content = new HomePage(dataProvider)
                    }
                }}
            });
        }
```

So how can I use page with complex contuctor using Xamarin Forms Shell? If it possible I would even prefer to do this from code behind (xaml.cs). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the flyout items in Burger Menu with Page like the following code

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection
        {
            Title = "home",


        };

        shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new HomePage() });
        ShellSection shell_section1 = new ShellSection
        {
            Title = "about",


        };

        shell_section1.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new AboutPage() });
        myshell.Items.Add(shell_section);
        myshell.Items.Add(shell_section1);
    }

}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to change action bar in the shell like this link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251620/title-bar-will-not-change-color