# Title Bar will not change color

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamrian forms 4.0 and for some strange reason my title bar is not showing as black even though I have set it to black in my colors.xml I am using the new AppShell application project is their an issue with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_background">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

This code is in the standard  xam forms app shell template.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
       <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ShellItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the action bar in the shell, it has a little complicated, First of all, we could set the background color by add  `BackgroundColor="Green"` in the shell .xml

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShellActionBar.Views"
  Title="ShellActionBar"
   BackgroundColor="Green"
   x:Class="ShellActionBar.AppShell">
```

But, The result like the following screenshot. The color of TabBar was changed to green.
[image]

Then, we should create styles for TabBar. Just for test, I copy default styles of TabBar,

```
  <Shell.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyBaseStyle" TargetType="Element">

        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ShellItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyBaseStyle}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>

 <!-- Your Pages -->
<TabBar  >
<Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png" >
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
</Tab>
<Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Strange its not appear to be honouring it for me.

Comment: @rogue39nin you can download this demo https://github.com/851265601/ShellActionBar, then run it in your android device, if it will change the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<Style TargetType="ShellItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />`

to

`<Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />`

It appears they have not updated the docs.